# How to create a temporary directory under a directory in bash

Tags: bash

How to create a temporary directory under a directory.
I tried `mktemp -d -p` but unable to figure out how to create temp directory under a give directory.

Please provide example with `mktemp`

Comment: Which platform? `mktemp` doesn't have a standard.

Comment: I'm using coreutils 8.13

Comment: And it doesn't work when ```mktemp``` version is 1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with mktemp from coreutils:

```
mktemp -d -p /path/to/dir
```